# preferred way of mixing ddl and dml in rails migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I run across this pretty often - as part of a migration I need to add a column, and set it to some value (let's say some computed value based on existing data). Since the dml isn't reversible, I typically do something like this:

```
class AddRatingsAndReviews < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :faults, :rating, :float
    add_column :faults, :reviews, :integer
    add_column :drills, :rating, :float
    add_column :drills, :reviews, :integer

    exec 'update faults set rating = round((random() * 2 + 3) :: numeric, 1), reviews = round((random() * 500) :: numeric, 0)'
  end

  def down
    add_column :faults, :rating, :float
    add_column :faults, :reviews, :integer
    add_column :drills, :rating, :float
    add_column :drills, :reviews, :integer
  end
end
```

However, I'd prefer to use a change migration. Do I just put the exec into a reversible block with a blank `down` portion? What's the rails thing to do here?

*edit* also - since the `reversible` method seems to have been introduced in Rails 4, what's the Rails 3 response here?